# Moving circle in agular2

Tags: angular

I'm trying to make a moving circle in Angular2, all looks fine except the CSS, as you can see I'm passing an object with 2 CSS properties into [ngStyle] and it doesn't actualize the `<div>` position until I reach the left or top border of the browser, when I do that, my `<div>` just "jumps" and sticks to the browser border. When I log the coordinates into the console it acts ok. I couldn't find if [ngStyle] refreshes continously or only in a specified case. Can somebody help me with fixing that ?

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-circle',
  template: `
  <div [ngStyle]="currentStyles" id="circle" ></div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./circle.component.css']
})
export class CircleComponent {
 
 currentStyles = {left: 50, top: 50};
 source: any = Observable.fromEvent(document, "mousemove")
                 .map((e: MouseEvent) =>
                 { return { x: e.clientX, y: e.clientY }})
                 .subscribe(cor => 
                 { this.currentStyles.left = cor.x,
                   this.currentStyles.top = cor.y});
}
```

Comment: What is the CSS  positioning property of your circle? `Relative`? `Absolute`? Also, have you tried using the CSS property `transform: translateY() translateX();` instead?

Comment: Positioning property is set to `Absolute`. I've tried now with the transform property and it doesn't work too I don't know if I did that correctly but I have added this to my "div"
`[ngStyle]="{transform: 'translateX(currentStyles.x) translateY(currentStyles.y)'}"`